# What's the difference in Qt between setVisible, setShown and show/hide

Tags: qt, pyqt, hide, show, visible

Please excuse this potentially noobish question but when trying to hide a QWidget what is the difference between calling setVisible(False), setShown(False) and hide()?

Comment: I think they all call the same code internally.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

`show()` is just a convenience function for `setVisible(true)`.

Similarly `hide()` is equivalent to `setVisible(false)`

Internally, the same code is used to render your view.

See http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.7/qwidget.html#show as an example. According to it,

> void QWidget::show () [slot] Shows the widget and its child widgets.
>   This function is equivalent to setVisible(true).

You'll find lots of such functions in Qt to just make things more **intuitive**, especially when it comes to widgets and views.

Comment: This is only partially correct. While it is true that `hide()` is the same as `setVisible( false )`, `show()` does more than just set visibility. Depending on the default state of the window, it'll set window state (incurring a window state change notification), and _then_ it invokes `setVisible( true )`.

Answer (score 9):

There is no difference.  They are just different ways of achieving the same thing.  (Actually setShown isn't really part of the API, it looks like it's a compatibility thing from Qt 3, so best not to use it.)