# How to hide a window in the constructor immediately after creation?

Tags: python, pyqt

I want to hide a window immediately after it is created. It works only if I do this with the help of button or something.

```
class Example(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Example, self).__init__(parent)
        self.hide() # doesn't work
        self.btn = QPushButton('Hide', self)
        self.btn.clicked.connect(self.click) # works
        self.btn.show()

    def click(self): # works
        self.hide()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently it seems that the code should work. What may be happening is that you are calling `show()` after creating the object. For example:

```
example = Example()
example.show()
```

Read this answer about `hide()` and `show()`: [What's the difference in Qt between setVisible, setShown and show/hide](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12178039/9427832)

Answer (score 0):

You can use QtCore.QTimer

```
class Example(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, app):
        QWidget.__init__(self)
        QTimer.singleShot(0, self.hide)
```