# I want to hide widget at the start of program

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, qt-designer

Know, I try to make GUI by using pyqt.
I want to hide some widget at the start of the program and show when I select Combobox.
It's possible to hide some widget at the start of the program. But, it's impossible to show a specific widget when I select Combobox. Could you please give me the advice for resolving this?

```
class MyForm(QtGui.QWidget):
def __init__(self):
    QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self)
    self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    self.ui.setupUi(self)
    self.ui.oneLayerWidget.setVisible(False)
    self.ui.twoLayerWidget.setVisible(False)
    self.ui.layTypeComboBox.clear()
    self.ui.layTypeComboBox.addItems(["Original Layer", "Boolean Layer"])
    self.ui.layTypeComboBox.currentIndexChanged.connect(self.layTypeSelEvent)

def layTypeSelEvent(self):
    layType = str(self.ui.layTypeComboBox.currentText())
    if layType == "Original Layer":
        self.ui.twoLayerWidget.setVisible(False)
        self.ui.oneLayerWidget.setVisible(True)
    elif layType == "Boolean Layer":
        self.ui.oneLayerWidget.setVisible(False)
        self.ui.twoLayerWidget.setVisible(True)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
class MyForm(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.ui.oneLayerWidget.setVisible(Ture)
        self.ui.twoLayerWidget.setVisible(False)
        self.ui.layTypeComboBox.clear()
        self.ui.layTypeComboBox.addItems(["Original Layer", "Boolean Layer"])
        self.ui.layTypeComboBox.currentIndexChanged.connect(self.layTypeSelEvent)

    def layTypeSelEvent(self, index):
        if index == 0:
            self.ui.twoLayerWidget.setVisible(False)
            self.ui.oneLayerWidget.setVisible(True)
        elif index == 1:
            self.ui.oneLayerWidget.setVisible(False)
            self.ui.twoLayerWidget.setVisible(True)
```

Answer (score 0):

If i understand you correctly you want something like this to hide your widget **self.ui.twoLayerWidget.hide()** and show your widget **self.ui.twoLayerWidget.show()**

It is also similar to **setVisible** see this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12177801/whats-the-difference-in-qt-between-setvisible-setshown-and-show-hide)

Or maybe you can consider using stackedWidget, you can change which widget to show out by changing the index

```
self.ui.stackedWidget.setCurrentIndex(1)
```

Comment: Yes, self.ui.twoLayerWidget.hide() and self.ui.twoLayerWidget.show() also work like setVisible. What i want to do is that widget hide and show when i changed combobox(layTypeCombobox). According to my code, when i select Original Layer of combobox, twoLayerWidget have to hide and oneLayerWidget have to show. However, it doesn't work. Always both widgets hide. I doubt whether self.ui.oneLayerWidget.setVisible(False) and self.ui.twoLayerWidget.setVisible(False) in def __init__(self): cause this problem.

Comment: maybe can consider using stacked widget for your case?

Comment: Yes! stacked widget might be what i want to make.

Comment: Please mark it if you think this is the solution for you :)